# How to upload video to Brightcove though API

Tags: php, laravel, api, brightcove

I am trying to upload a new video to Brightcove though API, at this point I managed to post just json data with information about the video, and everything is appearing fine in Brightcove, but I can't add video file which would be uploaded in Brightcove. I checked other answers, but they are not working for me as they are quite old. Thanks for help!

```
    $access_token = $this->getAccessToken();
    
    $data = array(
        'name' => 'test',
        'description' => 'test',
        'tags' => ['test']
    );

    $data_string =  json_encode($data);


    $url = 'https://cms.api.brightcove.com/v1/accounts/1774206337/videos';



    $ch = curl_init();


    curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
        CURLOPT_URL  => $url,
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $data_string,
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER     => array(
            'Content-type: application/json',
            "Authorization: Bearer {$access_token}",
        )
    ));

    
    $result = curl_exec($ch);

    dd($result);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've created a video object, and the JSON body of the response to that call will include the new video's `id`. You need to make an ingest request for that `id`.

If the source file is already accessible at a URL follow https://apis.support.brightcove.com/dynamic-ingest/getting-started/quick-start-dynamic-ingest-api.html and Brightcove will download the file to transcode.

If you need to upload a file, follow https://apis.support.brightcove.com/dynamic-ingest/getting-started/source-file-upload-api-dynamic-ingest.html

Comment: Thank you for your little explanation, but that was enough for me to understand how to do it. Finally, it's working perfectly! I never knew that we need to make 2 requests. Thank you, saved me a lot of time!